# Proving the intersection of Open Balls metric Spaces

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

Hi guys i was asked to prove the following:-

if $x \neq y ,\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 > 0, \epsilon_1+\epsilon_2 \leq d(x,y)$
then
$B(x_1,\epsilon_1) \cap B(y,\epsilon_2) = \phi$

My attempt at the question

Assume that $B(x,\epsilon_1) \cap B(y,\epsilon_2) \neq \phi$

$$let z \in B(x,\epsilon_1)$$ and

$$letz \in B(y,\epsilon_2)$$

$$\implies$$

$$d(x,z)<\epsilon_1, and,d(y,z)<\epsilon_2$$

Using the M4 axiom triangular inequality $\implies$

$$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(y,z)$$

$$d(x,y) \leq \epsilon_1+ \epsilon_2$$

can anyone tell me if this is right and if not what steps needs to be added to this proof to ensure it has been properly well stated ?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost rigt. You get $d(x,y) < \epsilon_1+ \epsilon_2$ (and not $d(x,y) \leq \epsilon_1+ \epsilon_2.$). This gives the contradiction

$$d(x,y) < d(x,y).$$

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification @Fred